# code giving Exception! can you figure out why? MSS

Tags: java, arrays, mss

My code on MSS problem is giving Runtime Error (Non Zero Exit Code) **when array size is more than max value of integer though I've solved the problem of array size bu using a 2D array but still getting error**. The code is running fine on my system.
 I can't figure out the problem. Can you?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
 class A{
 public static long max_sum_subarray_neg(long[] A,int n) //when all -ve elements
 {                                                           
     long ans=Long.MIN_VALUE;
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         if(A[i]>ans)
             ans=A[i];
     }
     return(ans);
 }  

public static long max_sum_subarray(long[][] A,int n,int k)  // for atleast one +ve element
{                                                      
    long sum=0,ans=0;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        if(sum + A[i][j]>0)
            sum+=A[i][j];
        else sum=0;
        ans= Math.max(ans,sum);
        }
    return ans;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    while(t-->0)
    {
        StringTokenizer s=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        int n= Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken());
        int k= Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken());
        s=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        int i,j,neg=0;
        long B[]=new long[n];                 //given array
        long A[][]=new long[k][n];            //array on which MSS has to be done after cpying value from given array k times
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)                    
        {
            B[i]=Long.parseLong(s.nextToken());
            if(B[i]<0)
                neg++;
        }
        long ans;
        if(neg==n)
            ans=max_sum_subarray_neg(B,n);
        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<k;i++)              //copying given array elements k times 
                for(j=0;j<n;j++)     
                    A[i][j]=B[j];    

            ans=max_sum_subarray(A,n,k);
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you look up the max allowable array size in Java?

Comment: Yes, array can supports size of Integer.MAX_VALUE. I've overcomed that problem by using a 2D array(in it I can store int max values in single row and int max value in single column). the problem is that I am getting Runtime Error, and I don't understand why